# How to add Average to the Pivot table in Excel?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have columns with count of Customers and count of orders. how can i show the average count of orders?

Answer (score 4):

Drop the orders column onto the Pivot layout again and then double click to select the summary method.

Comment: I could find a way to show average, or count, but not average of count. :(